# All my Cloud Functions say, function is active but last deploy failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Facing this issue with my Google Cloud Functions where from the very first function that I deployed to the ones I'm to upgrade today, are all saying the same thing on their status.

"Function is active, but the last deploy failed"

What may this be?

---

Here's the log visible for updating the function on the log explorer.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {},
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "start@pyme.team"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/pyme-webapp/locations/us-central1/functions/applicationSubmitted"
  },
  "insertId": "d1k3hyd3jfe",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "applicationSubmitted",
      "project_id": "pyme-webapp"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-02-02T20:23:05.726462Z",
  "severity": "NOTICE",
  "logName": "projects/pyme-webapp/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/cHltZS13ZWJhcHAvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvYXBwbGljYXRpb25TdWJtaXR0ZWQvaWdGS2o4bXpjbDA",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-02-02T20:23:06.263576440Z"
}
```

Similarly, all I see on the log in the function itself is:
[Image of the Function Log itself available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuLL.png)

The exact error that I am seeing and am concerned about and with is this: [Function Error with ORANGE HAZARD on update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjKZk.png)

---

Attaching another, even more detailed update log as well.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "start@pyme.team"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "80.83.136.68",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "FirebaseCLI/10.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2022-02-02T20:21:00.491300Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/pyme-webapp/locations/us-central1/functions/workContracts",
        "permission": "cloudfunctions.functions.update",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/pyme-webapp/locations/us-central1/functions/workContracts",
    "request": {
      "updateMask": "name,sourceUploadUrl,entryPoint,runtime,labels,httpsTrigger,availableMemoryMb,environmentVariables,sourceToken",
      "function": {
        "runtime": "nodejs16",
        "availableMemoryMb": 512,
        "entryPoint": "workContracts",
        "name": "projects/pyme-webapp/locations/us-central1/functions/workContracts",
        "sourceUploadUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-d393f99f-6b88-4b68-8202-d75b734aa7a1/64b2646f-35b6-4919-8e89-c662fc29f01f.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-748321615979@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1643835053&Signature=McjqD9mmo%2F1wLbvO6SklkHi%2B34nQEwcpz7cLOLNAF4RwG8bpHh8RThxFJwnGZo1F92iQnquRQyGYbJFuihP%2FUGrgW7cG6GmhVq2gkugDywngZXT9d7UTBG0wgKF29XcbZkwV3IX7oKKiUwf6Q6mzCOOoCrjc5LBxqJo9WvWDZynv8R75nVZTZ5IhekMdqAw%2BRvIBvooXa%2BuA3Sezhh%2Bz2BR1XtIyS21CY%2FkoPDaKPwvftr3%2Fjcyuzb2V39%2BSajQg3t0U7Gt6oSch9qUhl6gnknr6wphFGmC7t7h9l0LUbjHUDuaMNNoB1LXxI30CRNkRupf9XBKTKpKMf%2F0nAAMltA%3D%3D",
        "httpsTrigger": {},
        "labels": {
          "deployment-tool": "cli-firebase"
        }
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest"
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "us-central1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "1g6c2gwd46lm",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "workContracts",
      "project_id": "pyme-webapp"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-02-02T20:21:00.307699Z",
  "severity": "NOTICE",
  "logName": "projects/pyme-webapp/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/cHltZS13ZWJhcHAvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvd29ya0NvbnRyYWN0cy96bHlTLUtwbzI2VQ",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "first": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-02-02T20:21:00.985842395Z"
}
```

If this isn't the log to look for, just let me know what to find but I'd appreciate the help.

---

So turns out today morning, I login and check and everything is fine. I still have no logs stating the exact cause of the error but the same functions, the same code and the exact same deployment methods have worked and the function seems to be working fine.

This is concerning as separate cloud functions should never ever be changing on deployments.

A cloud function which takes in a POST METHOD and send data to SendGrid for example has nothing to do with a cloud function triggered by updates to the Firestore Database and if they're both deployed since the 5th of January and never touched again (in terms of edits), they should not be showing the same deployment error message across the board.

Comment: What is the error for the last deployment? Your question lacks details and context. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnHanley. I can post anything on this here yet, there's nothing either on my CLI Log that I have received or on the function log in itself.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I've attached all the logs that I am aware of. Other than that, deploying over the `firebase deploy --only functions` did not cause any errors or out of the ordinary behaviour for me.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your code and not at all with CF. When you get that the last deployment failed it means that your code crashed at runtime/build time and CF will continue serving with the last succesful version (i.e. your “old” code)

Comment: I agree with @FerreginaPelona. May I also know how did you manage to encounter the error?

Comment: I am not sure if this is an error with my code because 2 completely seperate functions should not be affected with the deployment of a new 3rd function. All 22 of my cloud functions showed the exact same error. 

The deployment logs and the logs generated afterwards have nothing useful in them. 6 hours later, all are resolved and working now somehow. To get this error, I just deployed the function from Firebase Deploy CLI and same happened even with the web editor.

Still unable to find the underlying reason. Everything is up and operational now though @RobertG

Comment: Tagging you for the same comment above @FerreginaPelona . 

One of my problems is that I'm only about 12 days into working with Cloud Functions myself and don't have a really expert understanding into them yet if you have any ideas on how I could check, log or understand this and what happened, I am more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

my temporal solution is to delete the function then deploy. It seems like it cannot be deployed while in use, i'm sorry i couldn't provide a better solution i will edit it as soon as possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).